# Regular expression to replace text between XML tags using Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, notepad++

Regular expression to replace text between XML tags using Notepad++

I need to **replace** all URL tag if containe **/mailto/**  **with ""**  in Notpad++

I need to find and replace text between html tags. Example:

xml:

```
 <urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/The-Praeger-Handbook-of-Learning-and-the-Brain-%5B2-volumes%5D</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/Learning-JavaScript</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/Category/183-Education/?start=868</loc>
        <lastmod>1970-01-01T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=4ae20e207319a25c17f554db7a4e9fa6f2694865</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=034b3c240db5c92e676bdf91b7b4bdffd725c428</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=c704ffd88b576782f9135da4848ab22a3cfb0f53</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=6b28532ecf1950b9e755938e65c1a1b6e466483e</loc>
        <lastmod>1970-01-01T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=a0ed06a8c2e075dbf1c1a23ae9203b2b464b166c</loc>
        <lastmod>1970-01-01T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=63e8e699f6db77096398c390d78fa1cd1ee34b6c</loc>
        <lastmod>1970-01-01T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=3a52445764cd71cad0a389f13b53faf5ae3a7dc5</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=9ea60360f4a81636f1e13f3a4e734016317d6179</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=jm_plus&amp;link=42c96ca4e0c746bd9155234a619be95300714953</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/Technical-Math-Demystified</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>0.00</priority>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

after replace:

```
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/The-Praeger-Handbook-of-Learning-and-the-Brain-%5B2-volumes%5D</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/Learning-JavaScript</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/Category/183-Education/?start=868</loc>
        <lastmod>1970-01-01T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
<url>
        <loc>http://www.file3.ir/last-books/183-Education/Technical-Math-Demystified</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-05-02T21:15:06+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>

</urlset>
```

help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

- Find what: `<url>[^<]+?<loc>[^<]+?/mailto/[^<]+?</loc>.+?</url>`
- Search Mode: `Regular Expression`. Make sure you check `. matches newline`.

This should remove the chunks you are after. You can then do the following: `Edit` -> `Line Operations` -> `Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank Characters)` to clear your input.